# Xamarin DequeueReusableCell for UINib always produces null

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I've created a simple view controller that has a table view on it. I've then created a .xib file to design the UITableViewCells that will go into the table.

No matter what I try `GetCell` cannot find the UITableViewCell nib. I've gone through every variation of name/id and casting. I'm very new to Xamarin and c# so I'm probably missing something simple.

**ViewController:**

```
public partial class ScheduleViewController : BaseViewController<ScheduleViewModel>
{
    [Export("initWithBundle:owner:extras:")]
    public ScheduleViewController(NSBundle bundle, UIViewController owner, string extras) : base("ScheduleViewController", bundle, owner, extras)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> itemData = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            {"phones", new List<string>() {
                "Android",
                "iOS",
                "Windows Phone",
                "Other",
                "The Thing"
            }},
            {"computers", new List<string>() {
                "osx",
                "windows",
                "linux"
            }}
        };

        UITableView table = new UITableView(View.Bounds);
        table.Source = new ScheduleTableViewSource(itemData);
        table.SeparatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;
        Add(table);
    }
```

**UITableVIewCell Class:**

```
public partial class WorkCell : UITableViewCell
{
    public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("WorkCell");
    public static readonly UINib Nib;

    static WorkCell()
    {
        Nib = UINib.FromName("WorkCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
    }

    protected WorkCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
    }
}
```

**WorkCell .xib file**

[image]

[image]

**TableViewDataSource:**

```
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // always null
        UINib nib = UINib.FromName("WorkCellContainer", NSBundle.MainBundle);
tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(nib, "workItemCell");
        var cell = (WorkCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("workItemCell");

        return cell;
}
```

Comment: If the problem is the UITableView is not dequeuing a cell from a storyboard. Try checking that you are using prototype cells instead of static cells. The UITableView will not dequeue a static cell.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT It's not from a "storyboard" but from a .xib. The table I instantiate through code. The layout for the cell I have in it's own .xib file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to load a nib in the GetCell method. Instead to use custom cells from an xib, you only need to do the following:

- create the xib with context menu (<Add/New File> choose `iOS`, choose `Table View Cell`)
- register the nib for cell reuse in your ViewController subclass
- set reuse identifier (for simplicity, just use the same name as the cell name)
- when dequeuing the cell use the reuse identifier

**Register NIB**

In your UITableViewController subclass in `ViewDidLoad` (e.g. just before setting the DataSource) add the following:

```
table.RegisterNibForCellReuse(WorkCell.Nib, WorkCell.Key);
```

**Set Reuse Identifier for Cell**

[image: reuse identifier]

**Dequeue the Cell**

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(WorkCell.Key, indexPath) as WorkCell;

    //set the data in work cell here


    return cell;
}
```

**Test in Simulator**

[image: test in simulator]

Comment: That's the same answer as mine as far as I can see... So yes this should work but he says it doesn't...

Comment: there are some small differences: no name for the xib, using the same name for reuse identifier as for the cell, make good use of WorkCell.Nib, WorkCell.Key in call of RegisterNibForCellReuse, doing that in ViewDidLoad - also describing just four steps to follow to get custom cells running - that should make life easier I hope

Comment: I still don't see anything but OK as they say your constitutional right to post the similar answer ;).

Comment: Ah, I see. I just tried to phrase it friendly. So the facts: 1) Your solution won't  work, because dequeueing will fail. 2) GetCell is called whenever a table cell is displayed. When users are scrolling that is potentially very often. It is consider bad practice to do something else there besides dequeueing and filling a cell. In a company during code review this code wouldn't pass review. 3) Especially it doesn't make sense to call RegisterNibForCellReuse each time a cell is needed (larger list, user scrolls, hundreds of times). Your mileage may vary.

Comment: As said I don't mind that you have copied my answer, it is allowed it is somewhat differently written and it may help the user that way. But don't pretend that you invented what you said above when it was already written in my answer word by word.

Comment: I don't see how your 'solution' would work. It will not dequeue a cell, so not solving the problem of the OP at all. And even if it would work it's not  considered to be a good solution for the reasons explained. But you are right:  I didn't invent anything here. It's pretty much standard code since the beginning of iOS.

Comment: I am not sure why are you pretending that my solution doesn't contain a clear recommendation to use ViewDidLoad and define reusable cell there and that you made improvement by doing just that?

Comment: Not arguing, that you gave a recommendation. Two reasons why I supplied an answer: first of all, take a look again at the screenshots and code of OP, then at your code. That will give an exception when trying to dequeue a cell, right? Also OP stated he is very new to Xamarin and also stated that he wanted to do it programatically in a specific way, so a guide how to achieve that easily in a clean, reproducable way could be helpful. Besides that, it is pretty standard way of doing it since the beginning of iOS. Nothing invented here at all from anybody I guess.

Comment: This works. One big thing to note is that the cell "Name" property needs to be left blank. If you don't leave that blank you get a "class is not key-value coding compliant". To me that seems like a bug in how VS Mac auto wires the designer file to the xib.

Answer (score 0):

This should work though you show only a portion of your xib file so I might got something wrong:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
        UINib nib = UINib.FromName("WorkCell", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(nib, "workCellContainer");
        var cell = (WorkCell)tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("workCellContainer");

        return cell;
}
```

While this should work, there is no need to register the tableView in GetCell, you should do that in ViewDidLoad it is a much better solution.

Comment: That didn't do it

Comment: You probably have UIView as the top view then and not UITableViewCell.

Comment: No I don't. See added image